# Type casting from a userdefined cast to double

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

I have to type cast from a user defined Lab type (which is of Lab space color type) to a double type.

```
static Lab heartColorLab(0.0,0.0,0.0);

heartColorLab =  _goals.getCurrentColorLab();

printf("updateScheduleLab %d {%d %d %d}\n", dtime, heartColorLab.L, heartColorLab.a, heartColorLab.b);
```

So i want the value of heartColorLab.L, heartColorLab.a, heartColorLab.b to be double. When i tried the c style type casting, the compiler gave me a error saying invalid cast from type ‘Lab’ to type ‘double’. So how do i convert from Lab user defined type to double.

Comment: `%d` in a format string means "decimal integer", "%f" is for floating point numbers (such as `double`), see [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

Comment: Yea, i know that, but since my HeartColorLab.L is a int type i cannot use %f in the printf statement unless i do type conversion before that.

Comment: Then I don't understand exactly what you want... `printf("%f", (double)(heartColorLab.L));` does not what you want? (Why do you want to print an integer value as a floating-point value?)

Comment: Why don't you reimplement `Lab::operator <<()` instead, and use code to print it `std::cout << "updateSheduleLab" << heartColorLab;` ?

Comment: @Dyp, yea thats why i did, but it gave me value like this 33.000 but the value i wanted was 33.456, so i am guessing, i would have to change the value to double before the print statement so that it can use the double value in the print statement. and the complier did not let me use                                                      heartColorLab = (double) _goals.getCurrentColorLab();